# iphone 3gs cameraoverylay shows only white screen

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay, iphone-4

I am creating the simple customized camera application.
so. i tried to customize the buttons for flash setting button and capture.
It worked for iPhone4 and iPhone4s... but unfortunately.. it shows the white screen on iPhone3gs.
What's the problem?

```
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X 1
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y 1

#define SCREEN_WIDTH  320
#define SCREEN_HEIGTH 480

- (void) showCamera
{    
    overlay = [[CustomOverlayView alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];
    overlay.delegate = self;

    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.picker.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
    self.picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    [self.view addsubview self.picker.view];
}
```

Comment: Try by presenting viewController as [ self presentModalViewContoller:self.picker];

Comment: Thank you. How should i do if the application have to shows picker When it launches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your showCamera method in your root view controller `viewDidLoad` method, or in its `init` method if you don't use IB.

You should present your camera controller by using

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewContoller:self.picker animated:NO];
```